# Can someone explain what this regex do?

Tags: javascript, regex

It's part of code where javascript should watch for some price and match if it's lover than required, but i don't understand regex quite well and it's obvious that the error is in there.

So on a website i have price like

```
<div class="item_price_now">   $ 1,34 </div>
```

And on javascript part code looks like this

```
var maxprice = '0.98';

var itemprice = document.getElementByClassName('item_price_now');
var i = 0;

var currentprice = itemprice[i].innerHTML.replace(/\s+/g, ' ');
currentprice = currentprice.substring(2);

if (currentprice > maxprice)
{ do some code }
else 
{ do some other code }
```

But this doesn't work, i assume that part of error is in regex, with this i don't get any values, i tried to change it to something like this

```
(\S+\w)
```

And it's outputing something (actually i get output of 1,34 ) but still can't match it with maxprice variable.

Can someone explain me what regex above means or at least point me in some direction. Thanks.

Comment: I've removed the `php` tag, as the question has nothing to do with PHP (and PHP's regular expressions aren't quite the same as JavaScript's).

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: This site [http://gskinner.com/RegExr/](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/) does a pretty good job of explaining regexes when you hover over each part

Comment: Note that the regex you show you have changed it to is `\S` not `\s` ie Uppercase `S`... `\S` matches NON-whitespace...

Comment: @AleksG Im trying to catch price lover than specific price (maxprice variable) and display notification when price is lover.

Comment: @ElRonnoco I have noticed that i changed s to S, it was my tryout on  purpose. I still don't understand how it works, but from readings, my guess was that i want to retrieve only characters and remove spaces, and w to retrieve only words and that would drop out $ sign and return 1,34 but i still dont know how to match it to work with lowest price i want to set.

Comment: I think h2ooooooo's answer is probably what you are looking for, ie `1,34` does not convert to a float. You will need to do another replace to change `,` to `.` before comparison - and preferably also use [`parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`/\s+/g` means "match any space/tab character that is repeated one of more times over the entire string".

Hence it's replacing any multiple whitespaces/tabs with a single whitespace.

It seems that your problem is that you use locale strings to describe your value, as you're comparing the string `0.98` (which is casted by JS) with `1,34` (which **cannot** be casted by JS, as `,` would be a thousand seperator)

Comment: I have read that about comma and i guess that i need somehow to replace comma with dot, or do something to match it like actual price.

Comment: @AleksandarĐorđević Will it **always** be displayed with a comma? If such, it's very easy simple to `'12,34'.replace(/,/g, '.');`

Comment: well, the problem is that price sometime is just 1 so there is no comma, and there is also no separator, so i don't know if it will recognize that 0.98 is lower than 1. ill check out for more info on this.

Comment: @AleksandarĐorđević If there's no seperator, then you can just replace. If there's no comma, it just won't replace anything.

Comment: Thanks for explanation, so i find out that using /\S+\w i will remove any spaces and signs like $ and just get raw number, and using your function i will get number with dot instead of comma, i just don't know how do i combine them to get final results. Do i use replace function twice, first to get number than to replace comma, or it can be combined in one replace, im trying to combine them but no luck.